# Late emergence of 3 stars and Shema repetition

Tags: zemanim, shema, time-zone

[Orach Chayim 235:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%90) rules that one has to repeat Shema after the emergence of 3 stars *(tzeit kochavim)* if prayed earlier in the evening. Many don't wait until *tzeit* in the summer on Fridays, pray earlier, and after the Shabbat meal they repeat Shema. However, חז"ל perfectly knew the issue with this ([Berakhot 4b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=4b&format=pdf)):

> ואומר אלך לביתי ואוכל קימעא ואשתה קימעא ואישן קימעא, ואחר כך אקרא קריאת שמע ואתפלל, וחוטפתו שינה ונמצא ישן כל הלילה
>
> **And says: I will go home, eat a little, drink a little, sleep a little and then I will recite Shema and pray.** In the meantime, **he is overcome by sleep and ends up sleeping all night.** <sub>(see [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.4b.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))</sub>

This Shabbat I had to do very serious efforts not to fall asleep, and unfortunately some parts of Europe are not in their [natural time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Europe) as well. For example in Paris, France, one had to wait until 23:02 on Friday (while at the eastern part of this time zone in Budapest it was only at 21:45). Is there a halakhically acceptable way to ensure fulfilling the mitzvah of Shema and go sleeping earlier?

Comment: See the Beit Yosef 267 who allows eating because of Rabbenu Tam. Not sure it's worth relying on that ordinarily, but with an alarm clock and in Shaat haDechak like northern countries you may find a Heter to eat early

Comment: Is your difficulty that according to your understanding one must eat only after reciting Shema and that adds a lot of time later on and you want to find a way to eat before Shema? Or just that the time for Shema is late and it's hard?

Comment: @DoubleAA On Shabbat eves we eat a very fine dinner, and this general risk of falling asleep is even higher. So in your terms the second one.

Comment: So you are accepting already that it is permitted to eat this fine dinner before saying Shema?

Comment: @DoubleAA I assume it's a commonly accepted practice, as I only know one congregation that prays _Kabbalat Shabbat_ with _tzeit,_ while numerous others that don't. Also found this one: http://dinonline.org/2011/10/25/eating-before-kriyas-shema-on-friday-night/

Comment: So is your question how it is permitted in light of that Gemara? I don't know what else you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The earliest opinion for the time for *arvit* and shema is (quoting from [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=When_Is_the_Earliest_and_Latest_Time_to_Pray%3F#cite_note-46))

> Rabenu Tam's (quoted by Tosfot Brachot 2a s.v. Meeymatai) argues that
>   really we hold like Rabbenu Yehuda in the Mishna (Brachot 26a) who
>   says that one may say Arvit from Plag Mincha, so too we hold that one
>   may say Shema from Plag Mincha.

(see also [here](http://israel.aish.com/smicha/RavCableSugyos/HilchosKriasShema/Review%20Sheet%20for%20the%20Times%20of%20Krias%20Sh'ma%20and%20its%20B'rachos%20(.doc) bottom of p. 1 and note 3)

In practice, I know no one who rules like this. However I asked your question once and was told that, `in case of need`, one could pray *Shema* as early as **24 minutes after *shkia*/sunset** (during the height of the summer in Europe). On the calculation of the 24 minutes, there are different opinions for how long there is from *shkia* to *tzeit hakochavim*, ranging from 20-45 minutes (see e.g., top of page 16 [here](http://israel.aish.com/smicha/RavCableSugyos/HilchosKriasShema/Review%20Sheet%20for%20the%20Times%20of%20Krias%20Sh'ma%20and%20its%20B'rachos%20(.doc)).

This might give you a direction to follow when asking your rav.

PS. I personally never relied on this *kula* when living 5 years in Paris but also recall many summer Friday nights trying to stay awake.

Comment: The OP cited Shulchan Arukh who rules against Rabbenu Tam regarding the earliest time for Shema at night. What exactly is this answer adding? It seems your answer is just reminding the OP that there are multiple opinions regarding when nightfall is so he should check where he's getting his numbers (such as 23:02 or 21:45)

Comment: @DoubleAA since not everyone as erudite as you are (and I mean it in all seriousness), it is an insight that one can pray 24 minutes after shkia in case of need/extreme situation. I personally previously thought one had to wait until nightfall. This is also what is indicated by a number of halachic zmanim calculator on the web (e.g., chabad). So for some of us the above might be helpful.

Comment: "ranging from 20-45 minutes" - I can't access your 2nd link, now. I'm curious if this is a universally true calculation everywhere in the world and during all seasons. For example, during the summer, north of the Arctic circle, the sun doesn't set at all for about 2 months. Thus, there is no *shki'ah* or *tzet*. Even in places where there is an actual night, when you're near that point, doesn't twilight take a very long time - possibly an hour or two?

Comment: @DanF you are exactly right and that was exactly the point. The Rav that gave that answer explained you can along with the night (3 stars or a bit before) or with a fixed time. Since R Tam allows shema already after plag he said the most lenient opinion was the shortest time after shkia

Comment: Besides that this is a very minority opinion, if you accepted this, shouldn't you follow this for the rest of the week? Personally, I have this problem only on Shabbat, as I only eat a light dinner on the rest of the days, therefore I wouldn't risk accepting this opinion on weekdays. Didn't your Parisian mates have another solution?

Comment: @Kazibácsi *lemaase* I didn't do this but it was mentioned to me as a solution for "tough cases", e.g., Scandinavia in the summer which is even worse